# Append two incremental columns to an existing file. Bash

Tags: bash, append

I have a file fileInput.txt, which contains a column X1. I need to append,
with an space, two extra columns temp(n), which have to be incremental and put it in an filetoCreate.txt

## fileInput.txt

```
  X1
string1
string2
string3
```

## filetoCreate.txt

```
string1 temp  temp1
string2 temp1 temp2
string3 temp2 temp3
.       .     .
.       .     .
stringn temp(n-1) temp(n+1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Are columns named exactly in consecutive order? or you are relying on line number?

Comment: your rule is incorrect. It should read: `stringn temp(n) temp(n+1)`

Comment: I am relying on line number

Comment: Fourat yes you are right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v num="1" 'FNR==1{next} {print $0,"temp"num-1,"temp"num;num++}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk -v num="1" '                      ##Starting awk program from here and setting variable num value as 1 here, OP could keep it as per their requirement too.
FNR==1{                               ##Checking condition if FNR==1 which means when line is 1st line then do following.
  next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{                                     ##Following statements will run apart from 1st line for Input_file.
  print $0,"temp"num-1,"temp"num      ##Printing current line, string temp, num-1, string temp and num as per OP need.
  num++                               ##increment num with 1 here.
}                                     ##Closing main BLOCK here.
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

OR in case your line number and variable value should be same then try following:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}{print $0, "temp"(FNR-2), "temp"(FNR-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With flexible **`awk`** expression:

Take a look how the output is *formatted* (no `temp0` there).

```
$ awk 'NR > 1{ printf "%s temp%s temp%d\n", $1, c, ++c }' file.txt
string1 temp temp1
string2 temp1 temp2
string3 temp2 temp3
```